# Regex for mismatched substrings

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to match some Java code that has mismatched strings in it. For example, I have the following block of code that I want to match:

```
protected String methodName(String args[]) {

    final String METHOD = "wrongMethodName";
    ...

}
```

And the following block of code I *don't* want to match

```
protected String methodName(String args[]) {

    final String METHOD = "methodName";
    ...

}
```

Right now, I have the following (not working) regular expression, which requires DOTALL enabled:

```
(\w+?)\(.*?\) ?{.*?METHOD *= *".*?";
```

If I try negative look behind with the capture group, the regex doesn't compile because the size of the look behind isn't known before hand.

```
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException:
    Look-behind group does not have an obvious maximum length near index 39
```

Is there a way I can use the capture group in this regex to say I want to match strings that don't match the capture group?

Comment: Why not just match `"final String METHOD = \\"\\p{L}*\\";"`
Can you be more specific what you wanna match. Do you know what the wrong and correct method name strings are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use a negative lookahead instead (if I understood your problem correctly), try:

```
(\b\w+?\b)\(.*?\) ?{.*?METHOD *= *"(?!\1).*?"
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2vdk0)

I used also word boundaries in the first group, otherwise it just starts matching at the second letter.